# Help with RGBS schematic

Tags: schematics, symbol

I am making up a cable for the below diagram, but am slightly confused about the shielding. Does this mean that the red (earth) should shield the yellow, white (earth) shield the orange, etc?

Does the black shield them all?

It is a diagram for an RGBS video cable between two car ECUs.

[image: RGBS diagram]

Comment: Welcome to this part of Stack Exchange :-) While I can interpret what I *think* that diagram shows, it would be helpful to get some confirmation. What other info / context do you have? Can you give a link to the source of that diagram, in case they have photos or other info about that cabling there? Is any part number given for the "bare" cable? That diagram *seems* to show the diameter of individual cores. That level of detail may be hard for you to duplicate. Are you trying to replicate some kind of custom-made cable yourself, where you don't mind if mechanical details are different?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is for a video module (J772 at bottom) to a display (J401 at top). The numbers in circles are earth points. The 'T' numbers refer to connectors, eg. T32f is a 32 pin connector. The '/' numbers are pin number.

Yes the numbers in the middle are the mm2 core diameter. Unfortunately no part number as it would be integrated into the cars complete loom.

I don't mind if the details are incorrect, I am happy with the main design, just not the shielding. Happy to use pre-made parts, but would like to custom make as much as possible as the lengths need to be precise.